# Facebook JS SDK: Is there any way to find out if the user has not accepted a permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Suppose I'm asking the user to access their basic public profile info and friends list (the default items). This brings up a popup (Accept/Cancel). In addition I'm asking to access fanpages that they manage. Currently on Facebook, this will bring up a SECOND popup, which the user can click `Skip` on.

If the user accepts the first popup, but clicks skip on the second (the `manage_pages` one), I want to bring up a message asking them to reconsider their decision, and explain why this permission is important.

Is there any way to determine that the user has accepted the first permission, but not the second one?

```
FB.login(function(response) {

    if(response.status === "connected"){
          //First permission was accepted, but not necesserily 'manage_permissions'
    } else {
         //The entire popup was not accepted
    }

 }, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
```

Comment: Did the answer help? Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The response object from the FB.login call does not include this info, so you need to make a second API call to `/me/permissions` and look at the response to that.

Quick example:

```
FB.login(function(loginResponse) {
    if ('connected' == loginResponse.status) {
        FB.api('/me/permissions', function(permissionResponse) {
            if (!permissionResponse.data[0].manage_pages) {
                console.log('user did not give app manage_pages permission');
            } else {
                console.log('user gave app manage_pages permission');
            }
        });
    }
}, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve that information using the user's access token. Facebook provides support for debugging an Access Token. You can retrieve the information related to a particular user's Access Token by issuing a GET request to the `debug_token` connection. Something like:

```
GET /debug_token?
     input_token={input-token}&
     access_token={access-token}
```

And this will return the following information:

```
{
        "data": {
            "app_id": 000000000000000, 
            "application": "Social Cafe", 
            "expires_at": 1352419328, 
            "is_valid": true, 
            "issued_at": 1347235328, 
            "scopes": [
                "email", 
                "publish_actions"
            ], 
            "user_id": 1207059
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the output contains information about the permissions associated with an Access Token. You can read the scope section to verify if the user has accepted any extended permission or not. You can get more information about it in the [Getting Info about Tokens and Debugging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug) reference.